# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2008 r2 with C# web project, Error: Connection string not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string

I have created basic login module in ASP.net using C#. I am using C# web application for this purpose.

Earlier I used SQL Server 2008 Express as a database. At that time application was running fine.

But then I uninstalled that database and installed SQL Server 2008 R2.

From that point onwards I am getting error:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)*

I found in `config.xml` I have code as:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS ;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

where  my SQL Server is called `MSSQLSERVER`.

This connection string must be the issue. But I am not able to resolve this issue.

Is my conclusion correct and can I get some help?

PS: my SQL Server 2008 R2 is installed correctly.

But whenever I try to connect with SQL Server 2008 R2 its connecting to 2008, which is uninstalled but have same name. (both earlier and this server have same name i.e. my computer name.)

Comment: Try to connect to the database through the wizard (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/images/connector-net-visual-studio-add-connection.png). This will generate valid connection string that you can use later.

Comment: I am not able to add correct connection this way. Its taking old SQL connection only.

Comment: `MSSQLSERVER` just means it's a default instance - try just using `local` as your server name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used following connection String:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="Server=EGT-GIS;Integrated Security=True;Database=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AddMarker\Map\Map\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF; Asynchronous Processing=False;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And it worked!!!

But just one concern, is this connection will be safe for Login database?

Got the connection string help from  Connection String and thanks to Marc_s

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, your SQL Server 2008 Express version was installed as the `SQLEXPRESS` instance - so your connection string would be something like:

```
server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=.........
```

or something like that (maybe you had the machine name instead of the `.` which stands for "local computer").

The new SQL Server 2008 R2 instance must be a **different** instance name - depending on how you installed it. If you used the default instance, then the instance has no specific name and your connection string should look like:

```
server=.;database=.........
server=(local);database=.........
server=YourMachineName;database=.........
```

If you installed SQL Server 2008 R2 with a specific instance name (that's something that **you** must know - we cannot know for you....) then use that instance name in your connection string:

```
server=.\INSTANCENAME;database=.........
server=(local)\INSTANCENAME;database=.........
server=YourMachineName\INSTANCENAME;database=.........
```

**Update**: AHA!! There's your problem!

> *The **user instance login flag** is **not supported** on this version of SQL
>   Server.*

Your connection string contains:

```
.....;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
      ****************************************************************
```

This "feature" (I like to call it a **flaw**) is **ONLY** available in the Express edition of SQL Server.

So when you've upgraded to a **full** version of SQL Server, you need to:

- attach your database to the server
- connect to use it using its logical name (and **not** supplying a `.mdf` file name)

So once you've attached your `ASPNETDB.MDF` file to the SQL Server 2008 R2 instance, change your connection string to:

```
data source=.;database=ASPNETDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

(or possibly use `GIS` as your data source/server name) and then you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer marc. But my instance name is MSSQLSERVER itself. and I am using the same name. But still I am getting the same error. Can there be any other issue?

Comment: @so_: are you sure your **instance** is called `MSSQLSERVER` ?? That's usually just the **service name** which corresponds to the default instance (the instance without any name). Have you tried just using `.` (or `JUSTMACHINENAME`) in your connection string? How do you connect to your 2008 R2 instance with SQL Server Management Studio? What "server name" do you use there?

Comment: I give "GIS"/"." as server name. but with "GIS" as instance its not working. Getting error as "The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed."

Comment: with your updated answer I tried with some another combination for connection. as: 
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="Server=GIS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=Fullpath/ASPNETDB.MDF;" />
  </connectionStrings>

With this it worked.. 
I think data source is also not allowed for SQLserve 2008R2. Need use Server only

Answer (score 0):

I think ".\SQLEXPRESS MSSQLSERVER"  is not your data source. Maybe only ".\SQLEXPRESS".

Comment: sorry its just ".\SQLEXPRESS" its not working.
Even I tried using just ".\MSSQLSERVER" but no rusult :(

Comment: Oks, the name of your datasource depends on your installation. If you have istalled SQL Server you have to remove the "AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true". Your conection string should be like "data source=.\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseNameHere; Security=SSPI". If you have installed your SQL Server instance without name, your datasource must be ".". Note your windows account should have permisions in your SQL Server.